# Using an Attribute Selector to Filter the jQuery .on() Method

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is probably something really simple that I'm overlooking, but I'm trying to filter an "on" click event in jQuery by an HTML5 data attribute, but it isn't firing.

```
$(window).on('click', '[data-mydata]', function () {
    // This never fires
});

$(window).on('click', function () {
    $(this).attr('data-mydata'); // <-- but this is the right value
});
```

Why can't you filter on data attributes? I've tried `'[data-mydata]'`, `':is([data-mydata])'`, and `':data(mydata)'`... and I'm left scratching my head.

In [the documentation for the `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) they filter based on different element types, but the CSS3 attribute selector doesn't seem to work.

This is version 1.11.2 of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need :

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-mydata]', function () {
```

instead of

```
$(window).on('click', '[data-mydata]', function () {
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zhxjjcq5/

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes you just need another set of eyes.